# Prolog existence error exception

Tags: debugging, exception, prolog

Firstly, I'm not a prolog programmer.  I'm doing an assignment for school where we build a small expert system.  I've chosen to use prolog for the assignment and I'm following this book: http://www.amzi.com/distribution/files/xsip_book.pdf.  Specifically I'm looking at chapter 2.

There is a procedure in this book that I would like to use called "ask."  It can be found on page 14.  Ask, uses another procedure called "known" to remember the answers to questions.  I have basically copied this procedure for use in my code, but I am getting an existence error related to the "known" procedure.  Not being a prolog programmer, I don't know how to debug it.  Hopefully someone can help.

Here is a sample run of my code:

```
| ?- species(X).
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,known/3),ask/2)
```

Here is the code:

```
species(limba) :-    %There are a bunch of these
    distribution(west_africa),
    color(tan_with_black_streaks),
    figure(plain),
    janka_hardness(670),
    workability(easy).

distribution(X) :- ask(distribution, X).
color(X) :- ask(color, X).
figure(X) :- ask(figure, X).
janka_hardness(X) :- ask(janka_hardness, X).
workability(X) :- ask(workability, X).    

ask(A, V) :-
    known(yes, A, V),
    !.
ask(A, V) :-
    known(_, A, V),
    !,
    fail.
ask(A, V) :-
    write(A:V),
    write('? : '),
    read(Y),
    asserta(known(Y, A, V)),
    Y == yes.
```

Comment: You want to build an expert system, but don't know *anything* about the language it is written in?  Good luck with that.

Comment: This program expects `known/3` to be *dynamic* (and the book you pointed to says this). That is, it's created and managed at run time. The Prolog documentation tells you how to declare a dynamic predicate. You might want to read through it.

Comment: Fixed.  As @lurker said known/3 needed to be dynamic.  I've added :- dynamic(known/3). to my code and it fixed the issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This program expects `known/3` to be dynamic (and the book you pointed to says this). That is, it's created and managed at run time. The Prolog documentation tells you how to declare a dynamic predicate. You might want to read through it. – lurker